# Are there any non-cash gas stations in Albania?

Tags: albania, contactless, gas-stations

Are there any contactless, card, paypal (or anything that isn't cash) gas stations in Albania, or are they all cash only?

Also, how to find English speaking stations?

I have checked reviews on Google maps and it doesn't seem any/enough info, as well as on travel exchange and traveler blogs.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Is your card not usable in ATMs?

Comment: @JonathanReez, many things. 1. ATMs have high commissions and hard to calculate exchange rate. 2. It isn't reasonable to take cash from credit cards. 3. Transactions are easier to track and remember for budgeting. Top 3 for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many networks of gas stations that accept cards and paypass payments such as ASR, BOLV to name a few.

The closer you to south, more places accept cards and paypass. In Tirana many places are still operating with cash, so you most likely will need cash from ATMs that literally everywhere in the city center and also at the airport.